# How to add a border to a Java Swing JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I've tried adding a border to a JScrollPane using the `setBorder()` method, but it didn't work. How can I add a border to a JScrollPane?

Comment: Post your [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JScrollPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), you can use setViewportBorder to add a border around the main viewport.

```
scrollpane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

Or you could add a border around the whole scroll pane using setBorder as outlined in [this Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html):

```
pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```